# Why is my code Getting ValueErrors with Tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Dear Stack Overflow Community, I have the following question:

Why am I getting a `ValueError` on the following lines that I will make Note of

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

data_path = "{Appropriate Data Path}"

# Load the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index("Date")

# Preprocessing
# Normalize the 'Number_OF_Tweets' data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df['Number_OF_Tweets'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Create sequences of data for the model
def create_sequences(data, seq_length):
    xs = []
    ys = []

    for i in range(len(data)-seq_length-1):
        x = data[i:(i+seq_length)]
        y = data[i+seq_length]
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

    return np.array(xs), np.array(ys)

# Use the function to create sequences
seq_length = 5  # Length of the sequence to be used for training (can be adjusted)
x, y = create_sequences(scaled_data, seq_length)

# Split data into training and test sets (use about 80% of the data for training)
train_size = int(len(y) * 0.8)
test_size = len(y) - train_size

x_train, x_test = np.array(x[0:train_size]), np.array(x[train_size:len(x)])
y_train, y_test = np.array(y[0:train_size]), np.array(y[train_size:len(y)])

# Reshape the data to fit the LSTM layer input requirements
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

# Model
# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=2)

# Prediction
# Generate a list of future dates until 2023-12-31
add_dates = [df.index[-1] + DateOffset(days=x) for x in range(0, 190) ]  # Adjust the range based on your last date
future_dates = pd.DataFrame(index=add_dates[1:], columns=df.columns)

# Concatenate the original DataFrame with the DataFrame of future dates
df_proj = pd.concat([df, future_dates])

# Get the last 'seq_length' values from the scaled data
last_seq = scaled_data[-seq_length:].reshape((1, 5, 1)) #Consider changing df.shape[1] to 1
#Above is another one of those lines

# Generate predictions for the future dates
for i in range(len(future_dates)):
    pred = model.predict(last_seq)
    df_proj.loc[future_dates.index[i], 'Predictions'] = scaler.inverse_transform(pred)[0]
    last_seq = np.append(last_seq[:,1:,:], pred.reshape(1, 5, 1), axis=1) #This is one of the lines
    
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Number of Tweets over Time')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Number of Tweets', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(df_proj.index, df_proj['Number_OF_Tweets'], color='blue', label='Actual')
plt.plot(df_proj.index, df_proj['Predictions'], color='red', label='Predicted')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I tried debugging accordingly, but I am still having issues with a ValueError and sort. If you can help me, that would greatly help me. The Error is mainly coming with variable `last_seq`. I am getting this Error Message right now:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d6f257be8343> in <module>
     79     pred = model.predict(last_seq)
     80     df_proj.loc[future_dates.index[i], 'Predictions'] = scaler.inverse_transform(pred)[0]
---> 81     last_seq = np.append(last_seq[:,1:,:], pred.reshape(1, 5, 1), axis=1)
     82 
     83 plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,5,1)
```

I tried changing these lines a bunch of times, but I kept running into issues.

Comment: First, you shouldn't be using `np.append` in a loop like this.  List append is more efficient.  With `axis` it is a just a call to `np.concatenate`.  Make sure you understand array shapes, and what `concatenate` expects.  And don't randomly through `reshapes` around.  A size 1 array cannot be reshaped to ANYTHING.  Do you know what `pred` is at this point?  Don't just guess or 'expect', I mean KNOW.

Comment: How much of this code is your own?  Or did you borrow it from tutorial or other website?  How much do you understand of basic Python and numpy?

Comment: I am still trying to learn it to be honest. I asked around got some help here and there. I am trying to use TensorFlow. I got it to actually run, but the problem was that it was stuck at 0 when it was learning even when I made the relu = 1. If you could help, I would appreciate it, but if you do not want to, I understand.

Thanks for helping.

-- Sid